# How to determine the locations of bars in a bar plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, bar-chart, errorbar

I've got a problem to find the exact location of a MATLAB bar-plot with multiple bars. Using the following code

```
A =[2.1974e-01   4.1398e-01   1.0889e-01   3.3550e-01;
   4.2575e-01   5.2680e-01   2.3446e-01   9.7119e-02;
   2.5702e+00   2.5594e+00   3.2481e+00   9.9964e-01];
b=bar(A);
```

I get the following plot

[image: bar plot with multiple bars]

Now I want to add stuff to that plot, e.g. error bars, text etc. For that reason I want to know the exact position of the individual bars.

I'm able to access individual properties using `b(1).` scheme, but I don't know which property belongs to the bar position. How do I get the exact location of each individual bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with the properties of

```
b = bar(A);
```

The specific properties you need are

1. `b.XOffset` The spacing between groups of bars
2. `b.XData` The index of each group of bars
3. `b.YData` The height of each bar

For the y-coordinates of the top of each bar, you can simply concatenate the `b.YData values.

```
yb = cat(1, b.YData);
```

For the x-coordinates, you need to add the offset to the indices

```
xb = bsxfun(@plus, b(1).XData, [b.XOffset]');
```

Now, you have the location of the top of each bar. Here's an error bar example.

```
figure;
bar(A)
hold on;
for ii = 1:length(xb(:))
    plot([xb(ii), xb(ii)], [yb(ii)-0.1 yb(ii)+0.1], 'xk-')
end
```

[image: Error bars on bar plot]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the figure property viewer to identifiy the properties of the bar postitions. Give it a try and change some values. Then you can access the properties and use the set function.

The values are the x- and y- values of the bars

Comment: Please elaborate this answer, as it's rather vague at this point. Please add a screenshot showing which buttons to click and where the numbers are shown. Better still: add a way to do this programmatically, so as not to have to hand-copy the numbers each time.

Comment: good idea, although I couldn't find the right variable again.  The only relevant information about the x-axis seems to be
`X Data Source = auto` which does not help

Comment: More than @Adriaan commented, this answer is wrong because using the figure properties will give the same x value to each of the bars in a specific group.